# My custom class always return 500 internal errror on Magento 2.1.2 ,but on 2.1.5 is work fine

Tags: module, sales-order, custom, order-status

I create custom status action class to change specific order to my custom status, I created "Packing" class, that change order status to 'packing'. it's working fine on Magento 2.1.5, but if I using it on Magento 2.1.2( I have some legacy product.) it always return 500 internal error.

This is Packing class which I overrode.

```
class Packing extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order {

const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_OrderStatus::packing';

/**
 * Packing order
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    if ($order) {
        try {
            $order->setStatus('packing');
            $order->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You put the order on packing.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('You have not put the order on packing.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
    return $resultRedirect;

}
}
```

please tell me if you need more code. Thank you for answering my question.

**edited**

debugger mode showed me `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context`

error function resides on Order.php from Sales Module.

```
/**
 * @param Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
 * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
 * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->_translateInline = $translateInline;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of internal server 500 kindly check system.log or exception.log in that you will find more about error.

for more do one thing. go to app/bootstrap.php in that uncomment below line approx line number 11

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

after that it will show you exact error. so you can get idea about what is wrong and you can fix that thing.

Try below code it will work for you.

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    $this->_translateInline = $translateInline;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answers, it show me `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context`. I didn't override any thing about this object. Have anythings difference between 2.1.2 and 2.1.5 about this object ?

Comment: Actually you forgot to call parent constructor that's why it is showing this error. 
you need to call parent controller then it will work in both version

Comment: thanks for reply, I already called parent construct and passed context like this `parent::__construct($context);`

Comment: please update your code in question

Comment: I already updated my question. the error line is reside in Order.php from module Sales.

Comment: thankyou for your help, I already tried your __construct code but it won't work.

Comment: Is it possible that the cause is a sequence of module loader on etc/module.xml of my custom module? Maybe context which passed to my custom class __consturct is not from magento module because of the wrong sequence.